# Question about Bitcoin in cash app

Tags: fraud, deposit, cash-app

Ok. So there's this man who said: "I will be making a mobile deposit of $5,150 from my crypto wallet  into your  cashapp and once the money is available you gonna keep 40% ($2,150) and send me  back 60%($3,000)."

Then he said: "Reason why I use people’s account to deposit my commissions, is because of banking limit & policies... and my money is currently in crypto currency, which is fluctuating, if I leave my profits there for too long I’d loose a lot of funds, which is why I’m using serious minded person’s account, and at the end I’d pay them 40%."

So the question I want to ask is: what are the risks if I do this? could there be something wrong that could get me in trouble?

Answer (score 5):

It is certainly a scam run by criminals.

At best you are knowingly engaging in money laundering stolen money on behalf of criminals - this makes you complicit in their crimes and you are the first person the police will find.

At worst, it is the initial stages where the criminals test your gullibility and either trick you out of large amounts of your own money, or get you involved in assisting them and then blackmail you.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to not go through with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a scam.

Things apparently play good to you, but then they convince you they have a sudden problem and they want you to advance the money. You now trust them, advance the money, but they disappear.

Comment: is there anyway I can safely find out for sure about whether or not it's a scam? I mean, if he's the one who's depositing money into my account through cash app,  and it's being done without giving him my personal information, then how does one get scammed? thanks 4 your response

Comment: They'd go a couple full rounds without issues first, then they'd propose a bigger round, but tell you something like the device doesn't allow them an atomic pay, so you trust them now, advance the money, they disappear.

Comment: if I decide to just play ball, and accept the deposit into my account, what's the worse that can happen to me? How do I proceed from there? Wouldn't he be the one out of money if I decide to not give him anything he asked for after depositing it into my cash app account? because I have no intent on giving him any of my own money 'cause he told me that there's no catch"

Comment: Once you decide to con the con people, you know both parties are mischievous, which is a factor to your favor, unless the con people know you are going to be malicious. Each party can make higher and higher bets and the "game" ends when one of the parties execute the con.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful!
they may disappear after u gave them money. not only persons, but there are also organizations who persuade you and after some time you can't reach them. their websites and emails and everything connected to them don't work.

Comment: After I give what money? The money he's giving me? Because that's the only money I'm giving. He told me "there's no catch." So if I decide to go through with it, what's the worse that can happen? thanks for your response

Comment: the crypto one. they are saying like as you will have the money profited. but there are bunches who don't give it